# How to Navigate a website using Treeview by DevExpress

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, treeview, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I'm currently using DevExpress' TreeView, which is being used to navigate throughout my ASP mvc site.

However, reading the [docs](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxNavigationAndLayoutDemos/TreeView/DataBindingToXML), I can't seem to find any reference to the actual navigation, especially when i'm binding the data from an `xml` file.

**My `ContentLeftPartialView`**

```
<div class="leftPanel">
        @* DXCOMMENT: Configure the left panel's treeview *@
    @Html.DevExpress().TreeView(settings => {
        settings.Name = "LeftTreeView";
    }).BindToXML(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/SideMenu.xml"), "/menu/*").GetHtml()
</div>
```

**With the basics of my `xml` being**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu>
  <group Text="Graphics">
    <item Text="General Overview" />
  </group>
  <group Text="Reports">
    <item Text="Report Manager" />
    <item Text="Product Delivery Report" />
    <item Text="Inventory Report" />
    <item Text="Stock Report" />
  </group>
 <group Text="Stocks">
    <item Text="stock 1" />
    <item Text="stock 2" />
  </group>
 <group Text="Systems">
    <item Text="system 1" />
    <item Text="system 2" />
  </group>
 <group Text="Lock Interface">
  </group>
   <group Text="Settings">
  </group>
</menu>
```

I am at a complete loss as to where I should be placing the `ActionLinks`/etc so that I would be able to navigate throughout my website (this panel will be persistent throughout all pages).

Has anyone got any experience with DevExpress' HTML 5 / MVC to point me in the right direction?

I know another project used this:

```
 public ActionResult Products()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your Products page.";

            return View();
        }
```

But it just used links like:

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Products", "Index", "Products")</li>
```

Which I don't think happens for DevExpress' treeview on a partial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to navigate using the `NavigateUrl` within the xml file, although this wasn't exactly where I wanted to place it (I would have preferred to add this dynamically).

However, using:

```
 <group Text="Graphics">
    <item Text="General Overview" NavigateUrl="/mygraphicsPage"/>
 </group>
```

Allows me to press the 'General Overview' on the `treeview` which will navigate to '`mygraphicsPage.cshtml`'.

So the important page is to add the

```
NavigateUrl="myurl" to the items.
```